# Length of sty file not displayed correctly

Tags: xetex, packages, conditionals, unicode

After building this code:

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass{report}        % or some other class
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
some text
\end{document}
```

I get the following warning in the log file:

```
...
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ifthen.sty"
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 1311 replaced by U+FFFD.
Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 1313 replaced by U+FFFD.
Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 1315 replaced by U+FFFD.
```

First, the ifthen.sty file I have is only 152 lines long. Second thing is, that I didn't include it in my document. has anyone experienced anything similar?

I use Win7 64bit, TexStudio 2.12.2.

Comment: The `ifthen` package gets included by `algorithm2e`. If you have a look at the source code of the `algorithm2e` package, you can see that the lines raising the warnings contain an `ç` and `ü`.

Comment: How to read the log file: if the opening `(` has already been closed by a matching `)`, then the message is not from opening that file. Look back to the `(` that opens the block with those warning messages.

Comment: Silly me. Indeed, after changing the encoding, it works fine. Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're just annoying warnings; the package should have

```
1307 \DeclareOption{turkish}{%
1308 \renewcommand{\listalgorithmcfname}{Algoritma Listesi}%
1309 \renewcommand{\algorithmcfname}{Algoritma}%
1310 \renewcommand{\algorithmautorefname}{algoritma}%
1311 \renewcommand{\algorithmcflinename}{\c{c}izgi}%
1312 \renewcommand{\algocf@typo}{}%
1313 \renewcommand{\@algocf@procname}{Prosed\"ur}%
1314 \renewcommand{\@algocf@funcname}{Fonksiyon}%
1315 \renewcommand{\procedureautorefname}{prosed\"ur}%
1316 \renewcommand{\functionautorefname}{fonksiyon}%
1317 \renewcommand{\algocf@languagechoosen}{turkish}%
1318 }%
```

instead of using Latin-1 characters for `ç` and `ü`. Turkish users will have surprises if they don't change manually those fixed words when using UTF-8 input.

LuaLaTeX users are in a worse situation, because the characters will issue *errors* and not warnings:

```
! String contains an invalid utf-8 sequence.
l.1311 \renewcommand{\algorithmcflinename}{
                                         ?izizgi}%
```

Unfortunately, there's no workaround for avoiding this while reading the package, so the warnings/errors cannot be skipped.

There is another error in `algorithm2e` (a spurious `{` at line 1061) that can cause memory overflow, besides issuing a warning at the end of the job. Making the bugs known to the package author seems useless.